# Drawing 3D graphics on top of an imported picture with asymptote

Tags: asymptote

I am trying to draw stuff on top of an imported picture with `asymptote`, following this [nice answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9559/drawing-on-an-image-with-tikz/129801#129801). Here is my MWE

```
     \documentclass{article}
     \usepackage[inline]{asymptote}
     \begin{document}
     \begin{asy}
     size(10cm);
     import graph3;
     import three;
     import labelpath3;
     import graph;
     import math;

     // it is not important which precise picture gets imported
     defaultpen(fontsize(10pt));
     real sc=2;
     unitsize(sc*1bp);
     real wd=120*sc;
     real ht=80*sc;
     label(
       shift(wd/2,ht/2)*
       graphic("earth.pdf"
       ,"width="+string(wd)+"bp"
       +",height="+string(ht)+"bp"
       +",scale="+string(sc)
       ),(0,0)
     );
     layer();

     int ngrid=10;
     int n=(int)(wd/ngrid/sc);
     int m=(int)(ht/ngrid/sc);
     add(scale(ngrid)*grid(n,m,yellow));

     xaxis( 0,wd/sc,RightTicks(Step=ngrid));
     yaxis(0,ht/sc,LeftTicks(Step=ngrid));

     draw(((0,0)--(wd,ht)/sc),blue+2pt);

     triple f(real t) {
       return (3*cos(0.125*2pi*t)+0.08*cos(2pi*t), 3*sin(0.125*2pi*t),0+ 0.08*sin(2pi*t));
     }

     path3 helix = graph(f, 0, 8, n=500, operator..);

     surface helixtube = tube(helix, width=0.4).s;

     draw(helixtube, surfacepen=material(blue+opacity(0.3), emissivepen=0.2*white));

     real R=300;
     real a=100;

     triple f(pair t) {
       return ((R+a*cos(t.y))*cos(t.x),(R+a*cos(t.y))*sin(t.x),a*sin(t.y));
     }

     surface s=surface(f,(radians(90),0),(radians(345),2pi),8,8,Spline);
     draw(s,gray,render(compression=Low,merge=true));

     // ---

     draw(((0,0)--(wd,ht)/sc),blue+2pt);

     \end{asy}
     \end{document}
     \endinput
```

It produces

[image]

As one can see, the 2-dimensional stuff, i.e. the grid and the blue line, really appears in front of the picture. However, the 3-dimensional stuff, i.e. the torus, does not. (No, of course I am not expecting `asymptote` to recognize that the imported stuff is also 3-dimensional.) I'd like to see the 3D stuff also in front of the imported picture. Is that possible?

(Of course, in the best of all worlds, somebody might figure out how to draw a 3D earth with e.g. `Mathematica`s GeoData in `asymptote`. Here I just want to put the 3D stuff in front of the background picture. It would be great if `opacity` would also work...)

Comment: I think that it is not possible in a simple way and with one asymptote commands file. With `asy -k` (keep intermediate files) you can observe the construction of the picture. You can modify it so that the torus is "at the end". But the white color of the 3D is not transparent. You have to modify the "white" color of the 3D png output with `convert` => "white" becomes transparent... In my opinion you have to process the final picture with two intermediate pictures (the 2D and the 3D)...

Comment: is https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/244785/asymptote-3d-label-background related ?

Comment: @jfbu it might be related, but with what is discussed there or in the link I cannot solve my problem

Comment: Another something that might be related (while it doesn't have anythong to do with asymptote, it has something to do with pictures in front of 2d pictures) https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/374998/coffee-package-puts-coffee-stain-behind-pictures

Comment: @ThorbjørnE.K.Christensen Yes, this goes into the right direction, but ultimately I'd like to make use of the nice `asymptote` features such as opacity.

Comment: @marmot I would look more into the `\AddToShipoutPictureFG` command, I think it holds the key, but i'm not sure

Comment: @ThorbjørnE.K.Christensen Unfortunately, playing with the `\AddToShipoutPictureFG` did ultimately not lead to a solution.

Comment: Can you please upload your import attachments so I can work with your full example? I do stuff with Blender und I'm interested in procedural texture generation (Substance Designer). I don't know anything about asymptote yet, but the question is interesting.

Comment: @CarpeDiemKopi The asy files that I import should be in every TeX installation. It is not important which pdf file you import.

Answer (score 10):

## 5th Approach: Wrapping a world map `sphere` with `surfaces`

A combination of the 2nd and 4th approaches.

Output:
[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
    \usepackage[inline]{asymptote}
        \begin{document}
            \begin{asy}
                import math;
                import three;
                import graph3;
                size(500);

                //file fin=input("world.dat"); //1317 limit for the for loop
                file fin=input("world_110m.dat"); //5254 limit for the for loop

                real zenith  = pi/12.0;
                real azimuth = pi/12.0;
                currentprojection = perspective(cos(azimuth)*cos(zenith),
                                                sin(azimuth)*cos(zenith),
                                                sin(zenith));
                //------------------------------------------------- TUBE
                    defaultpen(0.5mm);
                    pen darkgreen=rgb(0,138/255,122/255);

                    real R=3;
                    real a=0.75;

                    triple f(pair t) {
                    return ((R+a*cos(t.y))*cos(t.x),(R+a*cos(t.y))*sin(t.x),a*sin(t.y));
                    }

                    surface s=surface(f,(radians(90),0),(radians(345),2pi),8,8,Spline);
                    draw(s,surfacepen=material(gray+opacity(0.9), emissivepen=0.2*white),render(compression=Low,merge=true));

                //-------------------------------------------------- RING
                    triple f(real t) {
                    return (3*cos(0.125*2pi*t)+0.08*cos(2pi*t), 3*sin(0.125*2pi*t),0+ 0.08*sin(2pi*t));
                    }
                    path3 helix = graph(f, 0, 8, n=500, operator..);

                    surface helixtube = tube(helix, width=0.5).s;

                    draw(helixtube, red);

                  //--------------------------------------------------- PLANET EARTH

                    real r = 1.25;
                    real ar = 1.2;

                    path3 myarc = Arc(c=O,normal=X, v1=-Z*r, v2=Z*r, n=24);
                    surface sphere = surface(myarc, angle1=0, angle2=360, c=O, axis=Z, n=24);
                    draw(sphere, surfacepen=material(royalblue+opacity(0.9),ambientpen=white));


                    real[][] a=fin.dimension(0,2);
                    a=transpose(a);

                    for(int i=0; i <=5254; ++i){
                    real u=a[0][i];
                    real v=a[1][i];
                    real U=a[0][i+1];
                    real V=a[1][i+1];
                    if (u==360 & v==360 | U==360 & V==360){} 
                        else{
                            real x1=r*Cos(v)*Cos(u);
                            real y1=r*Cos(v)*Sin(u);
                            real z1=r*Sin(v);
                            real x2=r*Cos(V)*Cos(U);
                            real y2=r*Cos(V)*Sin(U);
                            real z2=r*Sin(V);
                            draw((x1,y1,z1)--(x2,y2,z2), darkolive+linewidth(0.2mm));
                            } 
                    }
            \end{asy} 
\end{document}
```

## 4th Approach: A world map `sphere`

Answer to:

> Of course, in the best of all worlds, somebody might figure out how to draw a 3D earth with e.g. `Mathematicas` GeoData in `asymptote`. Here I just want to put the 3D stuff in front of the background picture. It would be great if `opacity` would also work.

The package `pst-map3d` (`pst-geo`) offers the possibility to plot a [3D world map](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/62263/89320). The data set is based on the [CIA World DataBank II](https://www.evl.uic.edu/pape/data/WDB/). `Gnuplot` contains also a [`world.dat`](http://www.gnuplotting.org/data/world.dat) file with a low resolution world map data. [Natural Earth](https://www.naturalearthdata.com/) is a public domain map dataset available at [1:10m, 1:50m, and 1:110 million scales](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/). Based on the approaches [Plotting the world](http://www.gnuplotting.org/plotting-the-world/) and [Plotting the world revisited](http://www.gnuplotting.org/plotting-the-world-revisited/) given by [Hagen Wierstorf](https://hagenw.github.io/about/) on his website [Gnuplotting](http://www.gnuplotting.org/), its implementation in `asymptote` or `tikz` is possible.

#### Joining pair of points with `draw`: `draw((x1,y1,z1)--(x2,y2,z2), darkolive);`

The coastlines are drawn joining a pair of points.
`guide3` and `path3` in combination with `draw` and `surface` is used to fill the surface with a color.

```
     guide3 g;
     g=g--(x1,y1,z1);
     path3 s=g;
     draw(surface(s--cycle),heavygreen);
```

**Unfortunately, it does not work as expected. Any other ideas how to fill with a color the right surfaces?**

Output for modified ´world_110m.dat´ with fill color (small scale data):
[image]

Output for modified ´world.dat´ with fill color (low resolution data):
[image]

Output for modified ´world_110m.dat´ without fill color (small scale data):
[image]

Output for modified ´world.dat´ without fill color (low resolution data):
[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
    \usepackage[inline]{asymptote}
        \begin{document}
            \begin{asy}
                import solids;
                import three;
                import graph3;
                size(6cm);

                //file fin=input("world.dat"); //1317 limit for the for loop
                file fin=input("world_110m.dat"); //5254 limit for the for loop

                real zenith  = pi/12.0;
                real azimuth = pi/12.0;
                currentprojection = perspective(cos(azimuth)*cos(zenith),
                                                sin(azimuth)*cos(zenith),
                                                sin(zenith));
                real r = 1;
                real ar = 1.2;

                path3 myarc = Arc(c=O,normal=X, v1=-Z*r, v2=Z*r, n=24);
                surface sphere = surface(myarc, angle1=0, angle2=360, c=O, axis=Z, n=24);
                draw(sphere, surfacepen=material(royalblue+opacity(0.7),ambientpen=white));


                real[][] a=fin.dimension(0,2);
                a=transpose(a);
                guide3 g;                   
                for(int i=0; i <=5254; ++i){
                real u=a[0][i];
                real v=a[1][i];
                real U=a[0][i+1];
                real V=a[1][i+1];
                if (u==360 & v==360 | U==360 & V==360){} 
                    else{
                        real x1=r*Cos(v)*Cos(u);
                        real y1=r*Cos(v)*Sin(u);
                        real z1=r*Sin(v);
                        real x2=r*Cos(V)*Cos(U);
                        real y2=r*Cos(V)*Sin(U);
                        real z2=r*Sin(V);
                        draw((x1,y1,z1)--(x2,y2,z2), darkolive);
                        g=g--(x1,y1,z1);
                        } 
                }
               path3 s=g;
               //draw(surface(s--cycle),heavygreen);
            \end{asy} 
\end{document}
```

#### Building a `guide3` / `path3` with single points: `draw(p3,black)`

The coastlines as well as the colored filling are drawn with `guide3`, `paht3` an `subpath` in combination with `draw` and `surface`.
Unfortunately, it compiles only for the first 202 pair of points (`world_110m.dat`). For a higher number of points brings an error (the next pair of points (203)  is a new segment (`360 360`)). I have not found the error yet. **Any ideas?**

Output for modified `world_110m.dat` with fill color (small scale data):
[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
    \usepackage[inline]{asymptote}
        \begin{document}
            \begin{asy}
                import solids;
                import three;
                import graph3;
                size(6cm);
                //file fin=input("world.dat"); //1317 limit for the for loop
                file fin=input("world_110m.dat"); //5254 limit for the for loop

                real zenith  = pi/12.0;
                real azimuth = pi/12.0;
                currentprojection = perspective(cos(azimuth)*cos(zenith),
                                                sin(azimuth)*cos(zenith),
                                                sin(zenith));
                real r = 1;
                real ar = 1.2;

                path3 myarc = Arc(c=O,normal=X, v1=-Z*r, v2=Z*r, n=24);
                surface sphere = surface(myarc, angle1=0, angle2=360, c=O, axis=Z, n=24);
                draw(sphere, surfacepen=material(royalblue+opacity(0.5),ambientpen=white));


                real[][] a=fin.dimension(0,2);
                a=transpose(a);
                int j=0;
                guide3 g;
                for(int i=0; i<=202; ++i){
                    real u=a[0][i];
                    real v=a[1][i];
                    if (u!=360){
                            real x=r*Cos(v)*Cos(u);
                            real y=r*Cos(v)*Sin(u);
                            real z=r*Sin(v);
                            g=g--(x,y,z);
                            ++j;
                        } else{
                            int n0=i-1-j;
                            int nn=i-1;
                            path3 s=g;
                            path3 sp3=subpath(s,n0,nn);
                            draw(sp3--cycle,darkolive);
                            draw(surface(sp3--cycle),heavygreen);
                            j=0;
                        } 
                    }

            \end{asy} 
\end{document}
```

#### Joining pair of points with `Arc`: `Arc(O,r,one.y,one.x,two.y,two.x);`

An other solution could be to implement the approach from [Fill enclosed region on sphere](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/320885/fill-enclosed-region-on-sphere) by [Frenzy Li](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/109294/frenzy-li).

Output for modified `world_110m.dat` without fill color (small scale data):

(only for a few points (70) since `Overleaf` (free version) returns the error:  *Timed out. Sorry, your compile took too long to run and timed out. This may be due to a large number of high-res images, or complicated diagrams*).
[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
    \usepackage[inline]{asymptote}
        \begin{document}
            \begin{asy}
                import solids;
                import three;
                import graph3;
                size(6cm);


                //file fin=input("world.dat"); //1317 limit for the for loop
                //file fin=input("world_110m.dat"); //5254 limit for the for loop
                real zenith  = pi/12.0;
                real azimuth = pi/12.0;
                currentprojection = perspective(cos(azimuth)*cos(zenith),
                                                sin(azimuth)*cos(zenith),
                                                sin(zenith));
                real r = 1;
                real ar = 1.2;

                path3 myarc = Arc(c=O,normal=X, v1=-Z*r, v2=Z*r, n=24);
                surface sphere = surface(myarc, angle1=0, angle2=360, c=O, axis=Z, n=24);
                draw(sphere, surfacepen=material(royalblue+opacity(0.7),ambientpen=white));


                real[][] a=fin.dimension(0,2);
                a=transpose(a);

                pair[] region = new pair[];
                for(int i=0; i <=60; ++i){
                region[i]=(a[0][i],a[1][i]);}

                for(int i=1; i<region.length; ++i){
                  pair one, two;
                  if (region[i].x==360 & region[i].y==360 | region[i-1].x==360 & region[i-1].y==360){} else{
                  if(region[i-1].y < region[i].y){
                    one = (region[i]  .x, 90 - region[i]  .y);
                    two = (region[i-1].x, 90 - region[i-1].y);
                  }else if(region[i-1].y > region[i].y){
                    one = (region[i-1].x, 90 - region[i-1].y);
                    two = (region[i]  .x, 90 - region[i]  .y);
                  }else if(region[i-1].x > region[i].x){
                    one = (region[i]  .x, 90 - region[i]  .y);
                    two = (region[i-1].x, 90 - region[i-1].y);
                  }else{
                    one = (region[i-1].x, 90 - region[i-1].y);
                    two = (region[i]  .x, 90 - region[i]  .y);
                  }
                  path3 temp = Arc(O,r,one.y,one.x,two.y,two.x);
                  draw(temp,darkolive+linewidth(.3pt));}
                  }
            \end{asy} 
\end{document}
```

---

The original data contains blank lines to define the segment limits. These lines have been replaced with the pair `360 360`. For instance, the first lines of [`world_110m.dat`](http://www.gnuplotting.org/data/world_110m.txt):

```
    -163.71289567772871 -78.595667413241543
    -163.105800951163786 -78.223338718578589
    -161.245113491846439 -78.380176690584435
    -160.24620805564453 -78.693645928866943
    -159.482404548154477 -79.046337579258974
    -159.208183560197654 -79.497007745276406
    -161.127601284814716 -79.634208673011329
    -162.439846768218416 -79.281465346186991
    -163.027407803377002 -78.928773695794959
    -163.06660437727038 -78.869965915846805
    -163.71289567772871 -78.595667413241543

    -6.197884894220991 53.867565009163364
    -6.032985398777611 53.153190009160497
    -6.788856573910849 52.260117906292336
```

Modified `world_110m.dat`:

```
    -163.71289567772871 -78.595667413241543
    -163.105800951163786 -78.223338718578589
    -161.245113491846439 -78.380176690584435
    -160.24620805564453 -78.693645928866943
    -159.482404548154477 -79.046337579258974
    -159.208183560197654 -79.497007745276406
    -161.127601284814716 -79.634208673011329
    -162.439846768218416 -79.281465346186991
    -163.027407803377002 -78.928773695794959
    -163.06660437727038 -78.869965915846805
    -163.71289567772871 -78.595667413241543
     360  360
    -6.197884894220991 53.867565009163364
    -6.032985398777611 53.153190009160497
    -6.788856573910849 52.260117906292336
```

In this way, with a conditional expression it is possible to know when a new segment starts.

## 3rd Attempt: Wrapping a `label` with `surfaces`

I have tried a combination of the 1st and 2nd approaches. That is to say, trying to replace the planet by the imported picture.

There is a possibility to `draw` a `label` in 3D by using the base modules `three` and `labelpath3`. For example:

```
    path3 g=(0,-5,0)..(0,5,0);
    string world="earth";
    draw(labelpath(world,subpath(g,0,reltime(g,0.95)),angle=-90),orange);
```

gives the following output:

[image]

Since (p. 9 of the [documentation](http://vesta.informatik.rwth-aachen.de/ftp/pub/mirror/ctan/graphics/asymptote/doc/asymptote.pdf)):

> The  function `string graphic(string name, string options="")` returns  a  string that can be used to include an encapsulated PostScript (EPS) file.

I thought that defining

```
    real sc=2;
    unitsize(sc*1bp);
    real wd=100*sc;
    real ht=80*sc;
    string world2=graphic("earth.pdf","width="+string(wd)+"bp"+",height="+string(ht)+"bp"+",scale="+string(sc));
    draw(labelpath(world2,subpath(g,0,reltime(g,0.95)),angle=-90));
```

could work, but unfortunately it did not.

Code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
    \usepackage[inline]{asymptote}
        \begin{document}
            \begin{asy}
                import graph3;
                import math;
                import three;
                import labelpath3;


                size(500);
                currentprojection=perspective(
                    camera=(25,5,5),
                    up=Z,
                    target=(-0.6,0.7,-0.6),
                    zoom=1,
                    autoadjust=true);
                    //------------------------------------------------- TUBE
                    defaultpen(0.5mm);
                    pen darkgreen=rgb(0,138/255,122/255);

                    real R=3;
                    real a=0.75;

                    triple f(pair t) {
                    return ((R+a*cos(t.y))*cos(t.x),(R+a*cos(t.y))*sin(t.x),a*sin(t.y));
                    }

                    surface s=surface(f,(radians(90),0),(radians(345),2pi),8,8,Spline);
                    draw(s,surfacepen=material(gray+opacity(0.9), emissivepen=0.2*white),render(compression=Low,merge=true));
                    //-------------------------------------------------- RING
                    triple f(real t) {
                    return (3*cos(0.125*2pi*t)+0.08*cos(2pi*t), 3*sin(0.125*2pi*t),0+ 0.08*sin(2pi*t));
                    }
                    path3 helix = graph(f, 0, 8, n=500, operator..);

                    surface helixtube = tube(helix, width=0.5).s;

                    draw(helixtube, red);

                    //--------------------------------------------------- PLANET
                    material m=
                    //  diffusepen, ambientpen, emissivepen,  specularpen
                    material( green,      yellow,     blue,      black);
                    //draw(surface(sphere(1.2)), m);
                    //--------------------------------------------------- LABEL TEXT
                    path3 g=(0,-5,0)..(0,5,0);
                    string world="earth";
                    draw(labelpath(world,subpath(g,0,reltime(g,0.95)),angle=-90),orange);
                    //--------------------------------------------------- LABEL PICTURE
                    real sc=2;
                    unitsize(sc*1bp);
                    real wd=100*sc;
                    real ht=80*sc;
                    string world2=graphic("earth.pdf","width="+string(wd)+"bp"+",height="+string(ht)+"bp"+",scale="+string(sc));
                    draw(labelpath(world2,subpath(g,0,reltime(g,0.95)),angle=-90));
            \end{asy} 
\end{document}
```

## 2nd Approach: Wrapping a `sphere` with `surfaces`

Answer to:

> However, I want to create an output i which the tube wraps around the planet.

Output:

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
    \usepackage[inline]{asymptote}
        \begin{document}
            \begin{asy}
                import graph3;
                import solids;
                import interpolate;
                import math;
                import three;
                import labelpath3;

                size(500);
                currentprojection=perspective(
                    camera=(25,5,5),
                    up=Z,
                    target=(-0.6,0.7,-0.6),
                    zoom=1,
                    autoadjust=true);
                    //------------------------------------------------- TUBE
                    defaultpen(0.5mm);
                    pen darkgreen=rgb(0,138/255,122/255);

                    real R=3;
                    real a=0.75;

                    triple f(pair t) {
                    return ((R+a*cos(t.y))*cos(t.x),(R+a*cos(t.y))*sin(t.x),a*sin(t.y));
                    }

                    surface s=surface(f,(radians(90),0),(radians(345),2pi),8,8,Spline);
                    draw(s,gray,render(compression=Low,merge=true));
                    //-------------------------------------------------- RING

                    triple f(real t) {
                    return (3*cos(0.125*2pi*t)+0.08*cos(2pi*t), 3*sin(0.125*2pi*t),0+ 0.08*sin(2pi*t));
                    }
                    path3 helix = graph(f, 0, 8, n=500, operator..);

                    surface helixtube = tube(helix, width=0.5).s;

                    draw(helixtube, surfacepen=material(red+opacity(0.9), emissivepen=0.2*white));

                    //--------------------------------------------------- PLANET
                    material m=
                    //  diffusepen, ambientpen, emissivepen,  specularpen
                    material( green,      yellow,     blue,      black);
                    draw(surface(sphere(1.2)), m);
            \end{asy} 
\end{document}
```

However, the background is not transparent ...

## 1st Approach: Overlay of saved pictures in `Asymptote`

Answer to:

> I'd like to see the 3D stuff also in front of the imported picture. Is that possible?

Output:
[image]

Firstly compile the code `pdflatex asy pdflatex` to save the pictures and then compile it again by commenting the `shipout("");`´s:

```
 //shipout("D2FIG");
 //shipout("D3FIG1");
 //shipout("D3FIG2");
```

Code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[inline]{asymptote}

\begin{document}
    \begin{asy}
        size(10cm);
        import graph3;
        import three;
        import labelpath3;
        import graph;
        import math;
        // ----------------------------------------------------2D
            // it is not important which precise picture gets imported
            defaultpen(fontsize(10pt));
            real sc=2;
            unitsize(sc*1bp);
            real wd=100*sc;
            real ht=80*sc;
            label(
            shift(wd/2,ht/2)*
            graphic("earth.pdf"
            ,"width="+string(wd)+"bp"
            +",height="+string(ht)+"bp"
            +",scale="+string(sc)
            ),(0,0)
            );
            layer();

            int ngrid=10;
            int n=(int)(wd/ngrid/sc);
            int m=(int)(ht/ngrid/sc);
            add(scale(ngrid)*grid(n,m,green));

            xaxis(0,wd/sc,RightTicks(Step=ngrid));
            yaxis(0,ht/sc,LeftTicks(Step=ngrid));

            draw(((0,0)--(wd,ht)/sc),blue+2pt);
            shipout("D2FIG");

            picture D2FIG = currentpicture;
        // ----------------------------------------------------3D1
            currentpicture = new picture;
            size(10cm);
            import graph3;
            import three;
            import labelpath3;
            import graph;
            import math;
            triple f(real t) {
            return (3*cos(0.125*2pi*t)+0.08*cos(2pi*t), 3*sin(0.125*2pi*t),0+ 0.08*sin(2pi*t));
            }

            path3 helix = graph(f, 0, 8, n=500, operator..);

            surface helixtube = tube(helix, width=0.4).s;

            draw(helixtube, surfacepen=material(blue+opacity(0.3), emissivepen=0.2*white));
            shipout("D3FIG1");

            picture D3FIG1 = currentpicture;
        // ----------------------------------------------------3D2
            currentpicture = new picture;
            size(10cm);
            import graph3;
            import three;
            import labelpath3;
            import graph;
            import math;
            real R=300;
            real a=100;

            triple f(pair t) {
            return ((R+a*cos(t.y))*cos(t.x),(R+a*cos(t.y))*sin(t.x),a*sin(t.y));
            }

            surface s=surface(f,(radians(90),0),(radians(345),2pi),8,8,Spline);
            draw(s,gray,render(compression=Low,merge=true));
            shipout("D3FIG2"); 

            picture D3FIG2 = currentpicture;
        // ----------------------------------------------------Merge/Overlay
            currentpicture = new picture;
            size(10cm);
            add(D2FIG);
            label(graphic("D3FIG1+0_0.pdf"),(0,0));
            label(graphic("D3FIG2+0_0.pdf"),(25,-25));
    \end{asy}
\end{document}
```

I have taken the earth picture from [MATLAB script for 3D visualizing geodata on a rotating globe](https://www.asu.cas.cz/~bezdek/vyzkum/rotating_3d_globe/index.php)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It may very well be my fault because I may have not explained very well what I want. I do not want the white background be on top of these pictures. That is, if I am not mistaken, the current output can be obtained by just producing the pdf's individually and then putting them on top of each other. However, I want to create an output i which the tube wraps around the planet.

Comment: Your question was `I'd like to see the 3D stuff also in front of the imported picture. Is that possible?` Here my approach, and of course, my output can be produced individually, but I thought you were looking for a solution with only `Asymptote`. Transparency, than the same question as [Asymptote: 3D graphics with transparent background](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/379975/asymptote-3d-graphics-with-transparent-background?rq=1) and the [workaround](https://sourceforge.net/p/asymptote/discussion/409349/thread/0cfb1491/) is to use `convert` for png. May be you can open a bounty there

Comment: Fine. The intention was really different. If you have a way to make the background transparent and add it to the answer I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Unfortunately, not yet, but I keep on working on a solution

Comment: Your improvement corresponds exactly to my approach, which I found solely through the study of the documentations.

Comment: I've read more than once: `setting.render=0 has always transparency`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible to draw 3D graphics in front of an imported picture. That doesn't work with layering (2D) but by moving the objects directly toward (or away from) the camera (3D).

There are several ways to do this in Asymptote:

- label position parameter
- currentprojection.camera
- triple cameradirection
- triple towardcamera

Comment: Could you please add an explicit example?

Comment: I don't have the time for that at the moment, but I will give it later, because I also need it myself.

Comment: If you do it before the bounty expires, you get 500 points.

Comment: There is a grace period and if it really works I will award a new bounty in case you are too late. In its present form your post unfortunately does not answer the question.

Comment: If you happen to find a solution before I quit this site, I will be happy to award another bounty.