# Asymptote wrong 3D overlaping

Tags: asymptote

I just installed Asymptote to make a 3D model with annotations in LaTeX.

My model consist on several 3D objects and they are not overlapping well, it seems that they are being drawn in the same order that is in my script.

Here is my code:

```
import graph3;
import solids;
import three;

currentlight=White;

render render=render(compression=0,merge=true);

//body
revolution sph=sphere((0,0,0.0),1.0);
draw(surface(sph),green+white+opacity(1.0), render);

//arms
revolution armY=cylinder(O,0.25,5.0,Y);
draw(surface(armY),green+white+opacity(1.0), render);
draw(surface(shift(0,-5,0)*armY),green+white+opacity(1.0), render);

revolution armX=cylinder(O,0.25,5.0,X);
draw(surface(armX),green+white+opacity(1.0), render);
draw(surface(shift(-5,0,0)*armX),green+white+opacity(1.0), render);

//motors
revolution motor=cylinder(O,0.25,0.6,Z);

draw(surface(shift(0,5,-0.25)*motor),green+white+opacity(0.05), render);
draw(surface(shift(5,0,-0.25)*motor),green+white+opacity(0.05), render);
draw(surface(shift(0,-5,-0.25)*motor),green+white+opacity(0.05), render);
draw(surface(shift(-5,0,-0.25)*motor),green+white+opacity(0.05), render);
```

And this is my output
[image: Output image with wrong overlapping]

I think is a problem with

```
render render=render(compression=0,merge=true);
```

I also tried running the examples from the Asymptote page [3D examples from Asymptote site](https://asymptote.sourceforge.io/gallery/3Dgraphs/) and the answer code for this question [3D Asymptote examples from StackExchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/400164/drawing-3d-graphics-on-top-of-an-imported-picture-with-asymptote) but I always got wrong overlapping.

I installed Asymptote version 2.67 along with Ghostscript 9.19, all in Ubuntu 18.

Can you see anything that I am missing. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

For solid 3d rendering use raster output. for example, with command

```
asy -f png -noprc -render=4  3d-overlap.asy
```

we have

[image]

where `3d-overlap.asy` contains the code from the question with the `size` added:

```
size(9cm);
```